# linux, command to get the first non-system user id

Tags: linux, userid

Is there a linux command to get the first non-system user ID (first "real" user on the system) ? ( excluding root because of that https://superuser.com/questions/626843/does-the-root-account-always-have-uid-gid-0 )

Comment: Define what you call a non-system user.

Comment: will list all users: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257421/list-all-human-users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'whats the uid of the first user added by the useradd command' - Usually its 1000 (no idea how I know this though)

also, from a quick google search I found: https://serverfault.com/questions/362943/who-is-user-500

it appears that it used to be 500 was the first user, but it has changed to 1000

```
cat /etc/login.defs | grep UID_MIN
```

will give you the minimum user id for your system